# Looking for a way to run multiple image cyclers on one page.

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a webpage layout that has multiple images laid out in a grid. I'd like for several of these images to rotate through two or three different images, some at different speeds than others, with a fade effect between each image it's not so abrupt. I've searched for a javascript program, but all the ones I've come up with don't seem to favor having 5 separate images changing on the page at once. I've read several suggestions that you can just run the same program five times with five different names, but it's failed on every program I've tried (first one works fine, the rest just show static images).

I've got a solution going right now that makes all five images spin, but with no fade and all at the same time, so it looks like a really jerky, abrupt switch of five images at once, instead of a smooth fade transitions here and there. Also, after it runs a few cycles, it seems to start getting... stuck? and looks flickery and weird.

Oh, and each image is positioned absolutely with specific coordinates due to the grid layout, so I need something that won't cause problems with that (i.e. no frames/borders around the images, etc.).

What I currently have looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ready = 0;
var which = 1;
function isReady( ) {
++ready;
  if ( ready == 2 ) {
  ready = 0;
  setTimeout("swap()",6000);
  }
}
function swap( ) {
var i1 = document.getElementById("tst1");
var i2 = document.getElementById("tst2");
var i3 = document.getElementById("tst3");
var i4 = document.getElementById("tst4");
var i5 = document.getElementById("tst5");
var cur = which;
which = ( cur == 0 ) ? 1 : 0;
i1.src = i1.src.replace("-" + cur + ".jpg", "-" + which + ".jpg" );
i2.src = i2.src.replace("-" + cur + ".jpg", "-" + which + ".jpg" );
i3.src = i3.src.replace("-" + cur + ".jpg", "-" + which + ".jpg" );
i4.src = i4.src.replace("-" + cur + ".jpg", "-" + which + ".jpg" );
i5.src = i5.src.replace("-" + cur + ".jpg", "-" + which + ".jpg" );
}
</script>
```

With this HTML:

```
<!-- row a --> 
<!-- top row image (140px x 140px) that rotates in square a2--> 
<img id="tst1" class="a2" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-a2-0.jpg" 
  onload="isReady()"
  alt="brushes"/>

<!-- static image (140px x 140px) in square a3 --> 
<img id="estd" class="a3" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/img/2012-home.gif" alt="2012" />
<!-- top row large image (280px x 280px) that rotates in square a5 -->
<img id="tst2" class="a5" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-a5-0.jpg" 
  onload="isReady()"
  alt="stations"/>

<!-- row b -->
<!-- static image (280px x 280px) in square b1-->
<div id="logo" class="b1"><h1>Silk the Salon</h1></div>

<!-- static image (140px x 140px) in square b4-->
<img id="b4" class="b4" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-b4-0.jpg" alt="backsplash" />

<!-- middle row image (140px x 140px) that rotates in square b7 -->
<img id="tst3" class="b7" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-b7-0.jpg" 
  onload="isReady()"
  alt="floor"/>

<!-- row c -->
<!-- bottom row image (140px x 140px) that rotates in square c3 -->
<img id="tst4" class="c3" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-c3-0.jpg" 
  onload="isReady()"
  alt="stations2"/>     

<!-- bottom row image (140px x 140px) that rotates in square c3 -->
<img id="tst5" class="c6" src="/wp-content/themes/silk/images/home-c6-0.jpg" 
  onload="isReady()"
  alt="counter"/>
```

Any help anyone can give me would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very pretty and can be improved in many ways. I made a simple jsFiddle example to show you one or two ways to go:
http://jsfiddle.net/pASkk/

Some comments:

1. Don't use global variables, it will collide with other code. I have made a self-executing surrounding function to create a closure around all the code. This will keep it tidy.
2. Don't use inline coding (the "onload" attribute) Keep your js code separated from the html. Same goes for CSS of course.
   Actually in my example I found the onload unecessary. All code is executed after the part of the dom is parsed so in the example that is enough. You want to load your javascripts in the bottom of your page (not in the head) so usually this is enough. If you want to bind to onload anyway (and not use any library, like jQuery) see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html
3. Use setInterval for repeated swaps (or did I misunderstand you here?) and dont use strings for calling functions with setInterval or setTimeout; use an anonymous function instead.

I made a separate function for the single swap. I didn't have access to your image sources so you'll need to work on this one to get it the way you want. If you want to do some smoother image swapping I recommend using jQuery fadeIn (http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) or something similar. If you cannot use the library, you can check their source code to see how they made it.

best of luck

Comment: Thanks for your help and taking the time to help me clean up my code. I'm just sort of trying to learn JavaScript on the fly, so I'm not surprised that it was sloppy.

While that information streamlines the code I had, it doesn't really solve the major problem I was having. (I probably didn't explain very clearly.) I want the different images to fade in and fade out at different intervals, not have all 5 change at the same time. From what I understand of the code you wrote, it looks like there's only one interval to set, which controls how often they swap. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Also, I just found this, which explains the effects I'm going for a little better. [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/getting-multiple-images-to-fade-in-and-out-randomly) I don't fully understand the code suggested, though, or how to go about setting up the HTML to make it work.